# pass arguments without options when using argparse

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use argparse to only show help and usage and nothing else.

My current code looks like:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='remove-duplicate-lines-except-blank-lines',
                                 usage='%(prog)s [options] [files...]',
                                 description='Remove duplicate line except white space')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

To get help I can run:

```
$ python origname.py -h
```

and

```
$ python origname.py --help
```

So far, so good. However, when I try to use file names without options, for example:

```
$ python origname.py inputfile.txt optputfile.txt
```

If gives me usage and an error.

```
usage: origname [options] [files...]
origname: error: unrecognized arguments: inputfile.txt optputfile.txt
```

How can I pass arguments without options when using argparse?

Just to be clear, I am handling the rest of the argument (ex. inputfile.txt optputfile.txt) etc. manually using `sys.argv` so I do not need argparse for that.

Comment: why are you handling it using `sys.argv` instead of with `argparse`? that seems counterintuitive

Comment: @gold_cy this is a legacy code scenario. I want to use `argparse` to create `--help`, do not want to touch rest of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `parser.parse_args()` use [`parser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args).

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='remove-duplicate-lines-except-blank-lines',
                                 usage='%(prog)s [options] [files...]',
                                 description='Remove duplicate line except white space')
parser.parse_known_args()
```

---

```
==>python foo.py --help
usage: remove-duplicate-lines-except-blank-lines [options] [files...]

Remove duplicate line except white space

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit


==>python foo.py foo.txt
# nothing happens here
```